# gather data from multiple worksheets

Tags: vba

How can i get this to gather from 3 of the 9 worksheets in my workbook?

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyCCellVals()
 Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht6 As Worksheet
 Dim i As Integer, lastRow As Integer, sht6Row As Integer

 sht6Row = 5
 Set sht1 = Worksheets("MAINGANG")
 Set sht6 = Worksheets("REPAIRS")
 With sht1
  lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  For i = 5 To lastRow
  If .Cells(i, "C") = "X" Or .Cells(i, "C") = "x" Then
     sht6.Cells(sht6Row, "A") = .Cells(i, "A")
     sht6Row = sht6Row + 1
   End If
  Next
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Do you mean you want sht1 to be multiple sheets and paste to sht6?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Worksheets("name").select and then manipulate the data from there?
If there is something else you are trying to do please be more specific.

also this is code to loop through sheets:

```
Sub GetSelectedSheetsName()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
         MsgBox ws.Name
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but I "think" you want to gather data from multiple sheets and post to one sheet.

One way to do it is to set a worksheet array and loop through it.

Here is an example I put together on a new worksheet. I added a bunch of sheets called: `Hello`, `World`, `This`, `Is`, `A`, `Collection`, `Of`, `Sheets` and this code returned 3 message boxes showing `Hello`, `World` & `Collection`

```
Sub Temp()
Dim MySheets(2) As Worksheet, X As Long
Set MySheets(0) = Worksheets("Hello"): Set MySheets(1) = Worksheets("World"): Set MySheets(2) = Worksheets("Collection")
For X = LBound(MySheets) To UBound(MySheets)
    MsgBox (MySheets(X).Name)
Next
End Sub
```

You can use the MyWorksheets(X) object in the same way you are using sht1 but now you can loop through them by iterating X

If this is not the answer you are looking for please post back more detail of your requirements.

Also a side note, never use Integer when dimming in VBA, Always use Long. Search on this site for some great explanations of why.

Comment: sorry heres clarification, sheet1 will contain data with a value X in column "C" when there is an error, sheets 2 and 3 will also have the same thing, i want to copy the row containing the X value from all 3 sheets and compile into sheet 6.